# VSCode Extension "Live Server" and nginx proxy

Tags: nginx, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, nginx-reverse-proxy, liveserver

I'm wondering if anyone knows what the correct configuration is for getting the VSCode extension "Live Server" working with Nginx proxy. I want to proxy the extension from a subdirectory "/live".

The initial server shows up correctly via ex: https://example.com/live ...

[Live Server working with https://example.com/live](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YWlVP.png)

...however when I click a folder, "Live Server" removes the "/live" from the URL, resulting in a 404.

[Live Server cutting off "/live" resulting in a 404](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qZlvf.png)

Here are my "Live Server" proxy settings under the "Remote" tab

["Live Server" Proxy settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u7vKS.png)

Here is my Nginx location block configuration:

[Nginx block configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AG2xO.png)

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Have you fixed it yet